# Bounds on dimension of a purification?

Tags: quantum-information, density-operator

Let $\rho \in H_A$ be a density operator,  $H_A$ is finite dimensioal, it is well known that $\rho$ has a purification in some larger hilbert space. Let $b$ be the minimum dimension for $H_B$ such that there exists a purification of $\rho$ in $H_A \otimes H_B$.

Are there special classes of $\rho$ for which there is a known upper bound on $b$?

Comment: Surely you mean *lower bound*? One can always increase the size of the space by just tensoring it with itself, after all.

Comment: Oops I think I mean upper bound on the "minimal" purification

Comment: Updated question @acuriousmind

Comment: And before some smart person points this out, an obvious answer is that we know the answer for the case where rho is a pure state. Looking for a slightly less trivial class of states and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider any purification of $\rho$: $|\psi\rangle \in \mathbb{H}_A \otimes \mathbb{H}_B$. This purification necessarily admits a Schmidt decomposition of the form:

$$|\psi \rangle=\sum_i \sqrt{\lambda_i} |\alpha_i\rangle_A |\beta_i \rangle_B $$

with the state $\rho$ being of the form:

$$\rho=\sum_i \lambda_i |\alpha_i\rangle \langle \alpha_i |$$

This implies that the minimum dimension of $\mathbb{H}_B$, $b$, must be the rank of $\rho$. It follows that the upper bound on $b$ is the dimension of $\mathbb{H}_A$, and the class of states which saturate this bound are the states of maximal rank.

Is this what you're looking for?